# C# Email Client using an SMTP Gateway First?

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple emailer in C# for a customer of mine to notify them when a windows service (also c#) has stopped or been shutdown. I have been able to successfully test this and send an email notification from my test machine, but on the production machine it does not work. I spoke with their IT department and they said I have to route through their smtp gateway first...I'm not sure how to implement this in my c# code. The smtp host I'm using is "smtp.secureserver.net". They have provided me with an smtp gateway ip address. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question.  Instead of using the smtp.secureserver.net, you need to use your smtp server that you IT department has provided.

Comment: They are saying I have to route through their gateway to access my smtp server, I do not work for this company. Not sure if this makes sense or not?